# Raspberry pi 2 with new raspbian can't startx

Tags: raspbian, startx

I have a brand new distribution of raspbian running on my raspberry pi,

When I do `startx` it loads a bit. Then I see the wastebasket, but the menus just flicker on and off.

I checked my user `pi` for the right groups and it is correctly setup I think `audio video` group were present along with others.

How can I fix this?

**EDIT**

The basic xterm works, but when trying to go into safe mode the screen stops working entirely for both commandline and startx

The Monitor model
https://www.adafruit.com/product/2407

Comment: How are you viewing the screen? I am going to guess that you have an HDMI cable from your Pi to a monitor, based on the situation you described. It seems as if startx is working fine, but your connection has a problem which would cause the flicker. The other possibility is that the startx window is reloading rapidly over and over, which would cause the flickering appearance. It would be helpful if you could describe your setup, cables, etc.

Comment: it's not a flicker.. this is the computer rendering things funny.  It's just an HDMI cable going to an LCD touchscreen.  Also seeing this behavior on my asus monitor.

Comment: Hi @Erik, since the post has been brought up again... Did you solve the problem - if so you can always write your own answer. Did you check goldilocks' suggestions? Any good news? Feel free to share.

Comment: @Ghanima added comments to his response.  Will do further work before modifying my question.

Comment: Have you tried this pi with another display?  Does it work anywhere?

Comment: Have you tried another SD card?

Comment: @goldilocks the pi will output to other displays fine, but it's this behavior described across all of them

Comment: @avra yes, I've used multiple pi's and cards..

Comment: If it does that with multiple, different HDMI displays (and cables), it sounds like something is wrong with the GPU or the RAM it uses.

Answer (score 1):

Try something as minimal as possible.  First:

```
sudo apt-get install xterm
```

Now create an xinitrc file for your current user:

```
echo '#!/bin/sh' > ~/.xinitrc
echo xterm >> ~/.xinitrc
chmod 755 ~/.xinitrc
```

Check that it looks like the below w/ `cat ~/.xinitrc`:

```
#!/bin/sh
xterm
```

Now, as the same user, try `startx`.  You should end up with a plain black screen, an `X` shaped mouse cursor, and a (very primitive looking) black on white xterm window.

This is just to check if it is not something weird with the higher level GUI stuff.  You can exit w/ **ctrl-alt-backspace**.

In any case, you could also try adding this to `/boot/config.txt` and rebooting:

```
gpu_mem=128
hdmi_safe=1
```

I'm presuming this is an HDMI monitor.  Comment out any other `hdmi_` or `gpu_` lines by adding an `#` to the beginning.

If that works, have a look at [the documentation](https://github.com/raspberrypi/documentation/blob/master/configuration/config-txt.md#hdmi_group) for `hdmi_group` and `hdmi_boost` and experiment.  You'll have to remove `hdmi_safe` first -- there is documentation for that on the same page -- and possibly experiment with setting some of the things that sets (e.g., `hdmi_boost`).

Comment: I used `vim` to create the file, got a black on white window with a mouse.. the mouse didn't respond to my touch inputs (but that's another matter)

Comment: current entries I have were given to me by the vendor/manuf. adafruit
`hdmi_group=2, hdmi_mode=1, hdmi_mode=87, hdmi_cvt 800 480 60 6 0 0  0`

Comment: going into safe mode made the display unusable entirely (commandline no longer works)

Answer (score -2):

Try reinstalling Rasbian Jessie or try apt-get update && apt-get upgrade

Comment: um, this is a fresh install with all patches/upgrades.. no